# Clicking Yes button will add 1 and No button will Reset it back to 0. Just Like Streaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

**Help me writing the Javascript Please!!**

I want to make a streak just like the snapchat streaks when you click yes button and the streaks will be broken when the cross/reset/no button is pressed!

But here comes the Main thing that i want every users streak to be stored in their account ,for which i'll add Authentication on the Project Later!

I'm using MongoDB for storing Users and Streaks

The Streaks will be Displayed here:

```
<p class="mt-2 text-gray-400">
        Praying without any Break since
        <span id="streaks">0</span> day(s)!
      </p>
```

These are the Buttons:

```
 <div class="group relative flex justify-between items-center mt-2">
      <h1 class="text-lg">Have you offered all Prayers Today?</h1>
      <div class="flex flex-row">
        <!-- YES Button -->

        <button
          id="answer_yes"
          onclick="updateScores"
          class="flex p-2 m-1 border-2 rounded hover:text-white text-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-400"
        >
          <span>&#10003;</span>
        </button>

        <!--NO BUtton-->

        <button
          id="answer_no"
          class="flex p-2 m-1 border-2 rounded hover:text-white text-red-400 border-red-400 hover:bg-red-400"
        >
          <span>&#10007;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

THe Javascript i was trying was this:

```
const yes = {
    score: 0,
    button: document.querySelector("#answer_yes"),
    display: document.querySelector("#streaks"),
  };

  const resetButton = {
    score: 0,
    button: document.querySelector("#answer_no"),
    display: document.querySelector("#streaks"),
  };

  function updateScores(streaks) {
    streaks.score += 1;
    streaks.display.classList.add("has-text-success");
    streaks.button.disabled = true;
    streaks.display.textContent = streaks.score;
  }

  yes.button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    updateScores(streaks);
  });

  resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset);

  function reset() {
    for (let p of [yes, resetButton]) {
      p.score = 0;
      p.display.textContent = 0;
      p.button.disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

P.S: I'm a Beginner so bear with my useless and shitty Code! This my First Full-Stack Project and i can't even create the Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that your current code is all basic HTML and JavaScript and it is not working. So I made it work.

**After changing, this is your HTML code:**

```
<p class="mt-2 text-gray-400">
      Praying without any Break since
      <input id="streaks" value=0 disabled/> day(s)!
    </p>
    <div class="group relative flex justify-between items-center mt-2">
      <h1 class="text-lg">Have you offered all Prayers Today?</h1>
      <div class="flex flex-row">
        <button
          id="answer_yes"
          onclick="onYesButton()"
          class="flex p-2 m-1 border-2 rounded hover:text-white text-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-400"
        >
          <span>&#10003;</span>
        </button>
        <button
          id="answer_no"
          onclick="onNoButton()"
          class="flex p-2 m-1 border-2 rounded hover:text-white text-red-400 border-red-400 hover:bg-red-400"
        >
          <span>&#10007;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**And this is your JS code:**

```
function onYesButton() {
  if (+document.getElementById('streaks').value >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('streaks').value =
      +document.getElementById('streaks').value + 1;
  }
}

function onNoButton() {
  if (+document.getElementById('streaks').value >= 1) {
    document.getElementById('streaks').value =
      +document.getElementById('streaks').value - 1;
  }
}
```

You can check it now, the functionality works as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! it seems Working now, But i can't still store the clicks in  the Database. Also i want the button to be clicked once a day!

Comment: In order to save these entries in a database, you will be needing to call backend APIs in these functions. A backend that will do CRUD operations to the database.